# How do I find out the parent theme's style.css $handle

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to make a child theme in WordPress using underscores

WordPress handbook recommend to follow the below code when we enqueue the parent style.css

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

$parent_style = 'parent-style'; // This is 'twentyfifteen-style' for the 
Twenty Fifteen theme.

wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' 
);
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
    array( $parent_style ),
    wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
);
}
?
```

Here,

```
$parent_style = 'parent-style'; // This is 'twentyfifteen-style' for the 
Twenty Fifteen theme.
```

where,

**"parent-style" is $handle.** which is Name of the stylesheet.

Now how can i find my parent theme stylesheet name?

Comment: Just view the source on the front end, and find the stylesheet you want to know the handle of. WordPress will write the handle in the ID if it is properly enqueued. For example: `id='main-styles-css'`. The -css is automatically appended, so in this case the stylesheet handle would be `main-styles`.

Comment: Thank you. Your method is work properly. I find my handle.